# Obtener el color de un area o coordenada especifica de una imagen PNG O JPG al dar click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Necesito obtener el color de una imagen en una coordenada exacta donde el usuario de click, necesito que esto pueda ser posible con imagenes de formato png, jpg o svg.

Comment: que has probado hasta ahora? has mirado los eventos onclick, en un canvas donde tengas la imagen cargada para ver que informacion te da?

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo cargando en un canvas (invisible) la imagen y calculando la posición del click sobre la misma

Comment: hasta ahora, solo he logrado encontrar la coordenada en una imagen pero hasta alli estoy trabado https://codepen.io/KIDRP1/pen/pxaxbG?editors=1010

Comment: @PabloLozano dame un ejemplo por favor hasta ahora he logrado esto https://codepen.io/KIDRP1/pen/pxaxbG?editors=1010

Comment: @pabloLozano Che, hay alguna forma de obtener los colores en hexadecimal de una o tengo que convertilos de rgba a hex ?

Comment: El dato es un número (por tanto se guarda en binario), pero Javascript tiene [`parseInt(numero,base)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He aquí lo que tienes que hacer:

- crear un canvas
- calcular las coordenadas relativas del click sobre la imagen
- obtener el pixel correspondiente del canvas

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```js
const gatete= document.getElementById('gato');
const output= document.getElementById('output');

gatete.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let ctx;
  if(!this.canvas) {
      this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      this.canvas.width = this.width;
      this.canvas.height = this.height;
      ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  } else {
    ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        
  output.innerHTML ='R: ' + pixel[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixel[1] +
      '<br>B: ' + pixel[2] + '<br>A: ' + pixel[3];
                
});
```

```css
img,pre {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img id="gato" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" crossorigin="anonymous">

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Lo he hecho con puro JS, como puedes ver el código no es muy complicado una vez que se sabe lo que hay que lograr

Comment: Hola @pablo lozano tengo un problema con este codigo cuando uso imagenes locales el problema viene por el crossorigin="anonymous" como podria solucionar ese problema porque igual al quitar el atributo el javascript no me funciona

Comment: Define locales: ¿te refieres a que src es algo como `file:///C:...`?

Comment: <img width="800" id="imagen" src="img/masks.png" crossorigin="anonymous" >

Comment: la referencio de esa forma y no me muestra la imagen, y si quito el crosorigin me da error el javascript

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Estás usando un servidor para las pruebas?

Comment: me dice esto Access to Image at 'file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/color/img/masks.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: monta un servidor y te funcionará, accediendo a los archivos locales de tu PC hay restricciones de seguridad

Comment: Pablo mira lo subi a github y aun me da el mismo error

Comment: mira aqui esta   https://jcastillovnz.github.io/PRUEBA-COLOR/

Comment: no puedo tener la imagenes en un servidor local, me obliga que la imagen sea https

Comment: El problema que tienes es CORS. en la prueba de github que tenías las imágenes se cargaban desde `raw.githubusercontent.com`. Si el JS y las imagenes están en el mismo dominio, funcionaría