# ¿Como puedo obtener el color de un punto especifico con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, color

Estoy queriendo hacer un *color picker* para un proyecto que tengo, y estoy buscando la manera de poder detectar el color sobre el cual me posiciono. Mi pregunta ¿Existe algún método con *javascript* o *jQuery* para detectar el color del punto exacto?

Dejo el [link de lo que viene siendo el prototipo hasta ahora.](https://jsfiddle.net/nazsaciank/7stbhmyd/5/)

```js
$('.bg-selection .bg-pointer').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: "parent"
});
$('.bg-principal .bg-pointer').each(function(){ 
    var point = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;
    var parent = $(this).parent('.bg-principal');
    var width = $(parent).outerWidth();
    var height = $(parent).outerHeight();
    var top = $(parent).offset().top;
    var left = $(parent).offset().left;
    var x1 = left - point,
        y1 = top - point,
        x2 = width + left  - point,
        y2 = height + top - point;
    $(this).draggable({
        containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2]
    });
})
$('.bg-principal').click(function(ev){
    //console.log(ev)
    var bg_pointer = $(this).find('.bg-pointer')
    var x = ev.offsetX;
    var y = ev.offsetY;
    var point = $(bg_pointer).outerWidth() / 2
    $(bg_pointer).css({
        'top': `${y - point}px`,
        'left': `${x - point}px`
    })
})
$('.bg-all, .bg-transparent').click(function(ev){
    var bg_pointer = $(this).find('.bg-pointer')
    var x = ev.offsetX;
    var point = $(bg_pointer).outerWidth() / 2
    $(bg_pointer).css({
        'left': `${x - point}px`
    })
})
```

```css
.inputField .colors-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px silver;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-principal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-principal .bg-color-black{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #000 100%);
    z-index: 1;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-principal .bg-color-white{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    z-index: 0;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-principal .bg-pointer{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-principal .bg-pointer::before{
    content: "";
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 2;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-controls{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    margin: .5em 0;
    padding: .5em;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-color-view{
    min-width: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-selection{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-all{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, #ff0 17%, lime 33%, cyan 50%, blue 66%, #f0f 83%, red 100%);
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    position: relative;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-transparent .bg-color{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:  linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, red 100%);
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-transparent{
    margin-top: .5em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: url('../assets/transparent.jpg');
    background-size: 15px 15px;
}
.inputField .colors-box .bg-transparent .bg-pointer,
.inputField .colors-box .bg-all .bg-pointer{
    width: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% - 8px);
    top: -10%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="inputField">
  <div class="colors-box">
    <div class="bg-principal">
      <div class="bg-color-black"></div>
      <div class="bg-color-white"></div>
      <div class="bg-pointer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-controls">
      <div class="bg-color-view"></div>
      <div class="bg-selection">
        <div class="bg-all">
          <div class="bg-pointer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-transparent">
          <div class="bg-color"></div>
          <div class="bg-pointer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muy relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205446/obtener-el-color-de-un-area-o-coordenada-especifica-de-una-imagen-png-o-jpg-al-d/205492#205492

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tengo buenas y malas noticias:

#### Las malas

No se puede obtener el color de un pixel concreto de un div.

#### Las buenas

Se puede obtener el color de un pixel en un canvas:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const output= document.querySelector('#output');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', () => setColor(b.id)));

function setColor(color) {
  const horizontalGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
  const verticalGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(canvas.width/2, 0, canvas.width/2, canvas.height);
  horizontalGradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
  horizontalGradient.addColorStop(1, color);
  verticalGradient.addColorStop(0, 'transparent');
  verticalGradient.addColorStop(1, 'black');


  ctx.fillStyle = horizontalGradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = verticalGradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  
  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        
  output.innerHTML ='R: ' + pixel[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixel[1] +
      '<br>B: ' + pixel[2];
                
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
canvas,pre {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="red">Rojo</button>
<button id="blue">Azul</button>
<button id="green">Verde</button>

<canvas height="180" width="180"></canvas>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pondré a prueba lo que me dices. Saludos

Comment: Funciono de maravilla, gracias. Ahora tengo el siguiente problema, y es que quiero obtener la coordenada exacta con solo saber el color. Ya que si un usuario lo escribe a mano esta se tiene que posicionar automáticamente en el canvas.

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta distinta

Answer (score 0):

intenta algo asi

```js
$( "Tu_div" ).click(function() {
  var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
  alert( "El color es  " + color + "." );
});
```